# php pagination[1-last page], it comes back to current page when pressing a "2" or "3".. buttons

Tags: php, html

Here i written the query to display the data in 3 rows, it get the data from mysql database. It displays "1, 2 , 3" buttons. when i press the 2 button it doesnt goes to the next page. I think my sql query is not correct.. Please help me.

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $gender1=$_POST['gender'];
    if (!$connection) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("nursingcarein",$connection);
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $profession=$_POST['profession'];
    $state=$_POST['state'];

    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
        $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
    } else { 
        $page=1; 
    };
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 3;

    /*HERE IN WHERE IT MATCHES THE GIVEN "GENDER" in the textbox*/
    $sql = "SELECT age,description,name FROM nursereg WHERE gender='$gender' LIMIT 
    $start_from, 3";
    $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$connection);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs_result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo  $row['age']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo  $row['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    };
    ?>
</table>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM nursereg";
        $rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection);
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
        $total_records = $row[0];
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 5);
        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='ind1.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
        };
    ?>
```

Comment: By button you means those <a..> links you are creating at the bottom? Something I noticed that isn't connected to the issue. Your bottom query can be optimizes. Take a look at the mysql_num_rows() function. How many entries are currently in the DB, what's your total_records value end up being?

Comment: Should total pages be `ceil($total_records / 5)` when limit is 3?

Comment: Unless this is homework or to better your pagination skills, I would also suggest using a pagination class. There are many out there that provide a very simplistic interface and need almost no understanding of the underlying code.

Comment: When you echo `$sql` after selecting the second page does it output the query you would expect?

Comment: This most likely has nothing to do with your issue, but is a best practice and may help you find other issues in the future; you should really have done all the PHP calculations first before outputting anything and then output the HTML last when all the querying and preparing of the data is done. Then you can check the data and the UI separately of each other.

Comment: He has a minimum of 11 records to be `ceil(11/5) = ceil(2.2) = 3` to get 3 buttons in the bottom in the first place.

Comment: If OP is displaying 3 records per page then total pages of pagination should be divided by 3 not 5. If OP only wants 3 buttons total then the limit would have to be dynamic, which it isn't.

Comment: Also @Mario, you have to use a count in pagination. You can't use mysql_num_rows() since you are selecting a limit of <# of results per page> rows. If you used mysql_num_rows it would always be equal to the number of rows you limited your query to, which in this case is 3.

Comment: Please sanitize your inputs. Your code is highly vulnerable for SQL injections as you for example pass `$gender` directly from the user input to your query. Take a look at this: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com). Also don't use `mysql_*`-functions in new code. Check out *PDO* or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: I see what your saying, and I wasn't aware of that. What I don't see is how the bottom query is limited to 3. The top one is. To my understanding the amount of buttons/links is determined by the count of name from the second query. What am I missing?

Comment: How is gender being passed? Your initial query doesn't have a gender on page 2. I guess we don't know how it is passed for anything but the initial submission. Please correct me! Been wrong before :)

Comment: I passed the gender by giving input in the text box of the search items field.

Comment: How does page 2 get gender? Are you reposting the gender?